# Why isn't j incremented in (++i || ++j)

Tags: c, logic, pre-increment

I don't understand the output of this code:

```
 long i=5, j=10;
 if (++i || ++j)  printf("%ld  %ld\n", i, j);
 else  printf("Prog1\n");
```

The output is 6 and 10.  I expected 6 and 11.  Why wasn't `j` incremented?

Comment: Your if statement is evaluating an OR statement, so ++i is read first on the left of the pipes || and increments. It ignores ++j, hence why it ends up being 6 and 10...

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this, but you probably shouldn't... What's the effect you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logical OR operator `||` is a [*short circut operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  That means that the right operand won't be evaluated if the result can be determined by looking only at the left operand.

Section 6.5.14 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the Logical OR operator states the following:

> *4* Unlike the bitwise `|` operator, the `||` operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands.  **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

In this case, `++i` is evaluated and the result is 6 (with the side effect of incrementing `i`.  The logical OR operator evaluates to 1 (i.e. true) if either operand is non zero.  Since the left side is non-zero, the right side is not evaluated, and subsequently `j` is not incremented.

Answer (score 2):

Your if condition uses the short-circuited Logical OR operator `||`. As the left side of the operator (`++i`) evaluates to `true`, the right side (`++j`) does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Only `++i` was executed in `if` statement because `++i` is not zero and regarded already as `true`. Because of `||` OR operation, there's no need to execute `++j`.